# CraftCMS 3 Install from Backup - HTTP 503 - Service Unavailable HTTP Exception

Tags: craftcms

I messed my CraftCMS installation up trying to run an update. I uploaded my local backup files to the server, but now I get a 503 error and I can't figure out how to fix it.

HTTP 503 - Service Unavailable

craft\web\ServiceUnavailableHttpException in /home/######/vendor/craftcms/cms/src/web/Application.php:224
Stack trace:
#0 /home/######/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/base/Application.php(384): craft\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(craft\web\Request))
#1 /home/######/public_html/index.php(12): yii\base\Application->run()
#2 {main}

I tried uploading my local backup files.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried visiting `/admin`? There's a chance that there will be a button on that screen which you can click on to finish up.